# How to convert string date 'YYYYMM' to MonYY format?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to convert a string date variable in the form YYYYMM to a new variable in the form MonYY.

For example if the string is 201810 then the New variable would be OCT18 (the monyy. format in SAS)

Example:
`%let var = '201810';`

How could I create a new variable, say `newVar` in my desired format?

Comment: Please post anything you've tried. Do you have to have the quotes in the macro variable? That's a recipe for problems. And do you want a data set variable or a macro variable?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using macro, and a quoted value ?

**'201810'** to **'OCT18'** in macro environment

```
%let var = '201810';
%let var_as_monyy = %sysfunc(quote(%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(dequote(&var)),yymmn6)),monyy5.)),%str(%')));

%put &=var;
%put &=var_as_monyy;
```

**201810** to **OCT18** in macro environment

```
%let var = 201810;
%let var_as_monyy = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(dequote(&var))01,yymmn6)),monyy5.));

%put &=var;
%put &=var_as_monyy;
```

**'201810'** date string in DATA step and data set context

```
%let var = '201810';
data want;
  date = input (&var, yymmn6.);
  format date monyy5.;
run;
proc print data=want;run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways, one shows within a data step, which can also be used to create a macro variable and using only macro functions.

**Option 1:**

```
%let var = '201810';

data demo;

y=input(&var., yymmn6.);
z=put(y, monyy5.);
call symputx('newVar', z);
run;

%put &newVar.;
```

**Option 2:**

```
%let NewVar2 = %sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(dequote(&var)), yymmn6.), monyy5.);
%put &NewVar2.;
```

Comment: Thank you! A variation of this worked. I needed the quotes because of how i reference the variable later on, but I also have this variable saved without quotes.